# How to activate virtual environment withing npm script in package.json

Tags: python, node.js, virtualenv

How do i activate a virtual environment within a npm script?

```
    "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1",
    "dev": "virtualenv ../Scripts/venv && nodemon server.js"
},
```

I tried this but it wont work since virtualenv is not recognized as an internal or external command.

I have also tried to use source, and also just use the activate.bat file inside the environemnt.

FYI i am using windows.

Comment: Is virtual env installed as a global package ?

Comment: "I tried this but it wont work since virtualenv is not recognized as an internal or external command." Does it work at the command line? "I have also tried to use source, and also just use the activate.bat file inside the environemnt." And what happened when you tried those things?

Comment: @error404 How do i do that?

Comment: @EliasKnudsen are you getting any error ?

Comment: For me it is working `created virtual environment CPython3.9.16.final.0-64 in 491ms
  creator CPython3Posix(dest=/private/tmp/venv, clear=False, no_vcs_ignore=False, global=False)
  seeder FromAppData(download=False, pip=bundle, setuptools=bundle, wheel=bundle, via=copy, app_data_dir=/Users/ybagark/Library/Application Support/virtualenv)
    added seed packages: pip==22.1.2, setuptools==62.4.0, wheel==0.37.1
  activators BashActivator,CShellActivator,FishActivator,NushellActivator,PowerShellActivator,PythonActivator
test`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it by doing this:

```
"scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1",
    "dev": "sh -c '../DesignScripts/venv/Scripts/activate.bat && nodemon server.js'"
},
```